# Could not find file '..\bin\Debug\TestProj.UnitTests.xunit.runner.json'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019, xunit.net

I get the below exception when debugging an xunit test using .net MVC 5, .net framework version 4.6.2 and visual studio 2019.

**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Could
>   not find file 'Could not find file
>   '..\bin\Debug\TestProj.UnitTests.xunit.runner.json'.   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)   This exception was originally thrown at this call
>   stack:    System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int, string)

**

Please see the below images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for me adding this file was all it took `{projectname}.

and in the file content look like this

```
{
    "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json"
}
```

also don't forget to set the file to copy on build.

based on documentation found [here](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files#file)

Comment: Thanks. Just update the doc reference, link is now broken. You must have meant [this](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files#file) one.